# Configuring Eclipse for ResourceBundle

Tags: java, eclipse, resourcebundle

I have a java program which uses ResourceBundle that runs fine when I run it from the command line. My properties files are all in a dedicated directory and this directory is in my PC's classpath.

However, when I try to run the same program from Eclipse, I get an Exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ResourceBundle

How do I configure Eclipse so that it can find the properties files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not re-started eclipse after adding it into PC's classpath then please do so. I hope you should see it after doing that.

Comment: I've tried reloading Eclipse but it still get the same error.

Comment: Then you need to add the directory to your project classpath in eclipse